# What else can you do with a a PSM balanced/adjusted sample?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I am using PSM matching in a paper I am working on. Prior to doing the PSM, I look at some summary statistics, including doing some t and z tests; buyout is the treatment, control is the control:

[image]

My PI wants me to do this again after I balance the sample through PSM. Now, from [my reading of the MatchIT vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html), I know that I can use the covariates in the outcome model and doing so may make the robust standard errors doubly robust, but also that I shouldn't report them / interpret them as causal effects because their effects may be confounded:

> Although there are many possible ways to include covariates (i.e., not
> just main effects but interactions, smoothing terms like splines, or
> other nonlinear transformations), it is important not to engage in
> specification search (i.e., trying many outcomes models in search of
> the “best” one). Doing so can invalidate results and yield a
> conclusion that fails to replicate. For this reason, we recommend only
> including the same terms included in the propensity score model unless
> there is a strong a priori and justifiable reason to model the outcome
> differently. Second, it is important not to interpret the coefficients
> and tests of the other covariates in the outcome model. These are not
> causal effects and their estimates may be severely confounded. Only
> the treatment effect estimate can be interpreted as causal assuming
> the relevant assumptions about unconfoundedness are met.
> Inappropriately interpreting the coefficients of covariates in the
> outcome model is known as the Table 2 fallacy (Westreich and Greenland
> 2013). To avoid this, in all examples that incorporate covariates in
> the outcome model, we restrict the output of outcome regression models
> to just the treatment coefficient.

So, based on recommendations I don't think it works to take the balanced sample back and redo summary stats to show how they changed (I do include a balance table and love plots), but since the summary stats wouldn't be interpreting them as a **causal** model, I wanted to make sure I was right about that before I told my PI no (or yes?). So, basically, can I use post-balanced variables in analyses that aren't causal?

Comment: You already know you can use the covariates in the outcome regression model after matching, and you already know the covariates are balanced and you have to report that, and you already know you can't interpret the regression coefficient on the covariates, so what are you actually asking about? What "summary stats" and "analyses that aren't causal" are you talking about?